# How to refer a table from one chapter in another chapter in a report

Tags: reference, latex

I am writing a report, my document class is report, and I need to refer a table defined in one chapter in another chapter. I am using \usepackage{hyperref} too, however I am unaware of the code that has to be used in the text. Please help me to find a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `\label` and `\ref` commands:

- `\label` assigns a label (nomen omen) and can be given to an equation, a table, a figure.
- `\ref` is used to refer to a particular label.

For example, if you have a figure and assign to it the label `fig1` by using the command `\label{fig1}` then in the text you can refer to that figure by writing, for example

> As it is clear in \ref{fig1}, the colors are bright and vivid.

Take a look [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing) for some guidance. Down below you can find an example related to your question.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
A & B & C\\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3\\
4 & 5 & 6
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{A table}\label{tab}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1-3]
\chapter{Second chapter}
In this chapter we are referring to Table \ref{tab}. In the following we analyse the data and compare them to Table \ref{tab2}.

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
D & E & F\\
\hline
-1 & -2 & -3\\
-4 & -5 & -6
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Another  table}\label{tab2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

You may use also the [package `cleveref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) to let Latex handle the correct names of labelled environments (equations, tables, figures...).

Comment: Thank you very much @ Eddymage for taking the time to help me :):)

Answer (score 1):

You can use latex's `\label`/`\ref` mechanism like in the following example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter 1}

\begin{table}[htbp]
...
\caption{some table}
\label{mytable}
\end{table}

\chapter{chapter 2}

see my table \ref{mytable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @ samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz for taking the time to help me :). I have small doubt, when we use the \ref command it will show all the labels in the current chapter, and don't show the labels from other chapters, isn't it right?

Comment: @Mazreen No, labels are document wide. You must use unique labels throughout the document.

Comment: Thank you very much @ samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz for your quick reply :):)